# CSS added through customizer neglects the need of a child theme?

Tags: theme-development, customization, css

Many developers know that if you change the style.css of a theme, and then the theme gets updated, your changes will be deleted.

The traditional solution for that is creating a child theme inheriting everything from the parent theme, while changing the child theme's CSS.

But what about a case when I change the CSS of a theme from Wordpress itself, as can be done from the Wordpress customizer?

Will this CSS also be changed if the theme is updated? I would bet it won't 99.99% but it wasn't clear from any documentation I've read so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mods you enter into the Customizer are kept safe over upgrades, as they are saved into the database. But styles are not the only reason for a need of a child theme. Often you need to add functions/hooks and several other customiziation which - in that case - need a specific child theme.